# Compile LESS files to CSS

Tags: 8, theming

How can i preprocessor or compile at runtime the LESS files in the latest version of Drupal 8?

I am using the LESS starterkit theme of Bootstrap. The **Less CSS Preprocessor** is currently not ported to Drupal 8.

The next two guides says that i need NodeJS and the less package to compile it, but it is not at the runtime of Drupal:

```
lessc less/style.less > css/style.css
```

1. [Creating a Bootstrap subtheme for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2781903)
2. [How to build your Drupal 8 theme using Bootstrap & Less](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-build-your-drupal-8-theme-using-bootstrap-less)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to wait for the port of the Less CSS Preprocessor module to run the less compiler at run time, you can execute the command line tool from **settings.php**

```
exec('lessc themes/mytheme/less/style.less themes/mytheme/css/style.css > /tmp/less-debug 2>&1');
```

This is only for development, remove this from the production settings.php.

Comment: This is interesting, I haven't seen this approach before.

Answer (score 2):

`lessc` is referring to this npm package:

http://lesscss.org/

You could either install it globally, or have it at the theme level with your own package.json and execute it from the theme directory.

To install globally with npm:

```
npm install -g less
```

`lessc` is then a command available at your command line and then your compile command will work.

See: http://lesscss.org/#using-less-installation

Comment: It returns: **Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc**

It should be `npm install -g less`

Comment: Sorry typo. Corrected